# How to generate time series from a series of ordered numbers in Python's pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using DataFrame in pandas to analyse data. A sample:

```
data[:5]
        time   qlen     means      vars
1   1.153281      1  0.000000  0.000000
2   5.279293      1  0.333333  0.222222
3   12.285338     1  0.400000  0.240000
4   16.407872     1  0.428571  0.244898
5   23.184910     1  0.444444  0.246914
```

with the 'time' column in seconds.

How do I convert the float values of 'time' to actual time series?

I have tried `pandas.date_range` but couldn't find a suitable way of doing it, mostly because the time points don't happen on equal intervals.

Comment: You could add base date to `time`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the times as a `timedelta` (i.e. dateless) type, use the `to_timedelta` conversion function, specifying the unit.

```
In [11]: pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='s')
Out[11]: 
1   00:00:01.153281
2   00:00:05.279293
3   00:00:12.285338
4   00:00:16.407872
5   00:00:23.184910
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you want the times as of a particular date, just add the delta to it.

```
In [12]: pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='s') + pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01')
Out[12]: 
1   2014-01-01 00:00:01.153281
2   2014-01-01 00:00:05.279293
3   2014-01-01 00:00:12.285338
4   2014-01-01 00:00:16.407872
5   2014-01-01 00:00:23.184910
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```